# Laravel passport Oauth2 "Requesting Tokens"

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-5.5, laravel-passport, zapier

I am working with Zapier, and trying to authenticate user using OAuth2. I am using the Laravel(5.5) Passport(^4.0).

I am trying to use defalut passport routes "https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport".

But when it goes to "oauth/authorize" GET method and if user is not logged in then gives me `{"error":"Unauthenticated."}` instead of redirecting to Login page. And if user is logged in already then worked well.

Is there something i am missing and where I can check to resolve this issue.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

You are working with Oauth2 so you will get `401` and `{"error" : "Unauthenticated"}`. It is up to you to handle the unauthenticated response to the server (e.g. your js front end will redirect or your mobile app show login page).

Comment: @Nguyen, Thanks for reply. We have used VUE for frontend, To test i have intalled the fresh laravel 5.5 project, Where everything is working fine. Is there any file from where i can check why it is not redirecting to login page for "oauth/authorize" url when user is not logged in to system.